# How to trace Subset from Boolean DP table in the Subset Sum Problem

Tags: data-structures, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I have seen that the Subset Sum Problem can be solved using Dynamic programming and we should look up the Last row's last column to return the result.

My questions are.

1. How did someone conclude that the Last row's last column will give us the result?
2. How can we trace from there to check the subset that can be added to get the Sum?
3. Finally, is there a way to trace all the possible subsets from this DP table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Manoj, you need to focus your post to one single question. As of now it feels broad. Go through Subset sum problem so many times so that you understand it lot better. Then read this link to get your answers https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-sum-problem-print-subsets-given-sum/.

Comment: Moreover, I don't know what "Last row" or "last column" means in this setting. You will have to describe the dynamic programming algorithm you are referring to.

Comment: @Shridhar R Kulkarni Thanks for your comment.  I understood and I have written code too using Swift for Both DP and Backtracking approach. Perfect Sum Problem in geek for geeks is not that efficient. It's using both DP and Brute Force to print the result. That's y I actually came here.

Comment: @ Yuval Filmus It's too broad the explain it here, sorry. I thought someone who's already trying to solve the NP-Complete problems can help me.

Comment: @Manoj: DP is used to figure out if subset exists. What you say brute force is not really brute force if you trace. It is just backtracking on the DP table that has been constructed. As all the subsets need to be printed, algorithmic complexity can't be better.

Comment: Exactly it's BT on DP table not BF. I'm just trying to see if we can find the subsets while building the Table while without Doing BT.